# php5-fpm spike, wrong configuration?

Tags: php, nginx, configuration, php-fpm, optimization

Recently I've uploaded some changes to my server that increases the amount of AJAX calls made to the server.

The application "fastness" has decreased a lot. The web server is nginx with php5-fpm module

If I run a "top" command on the server console I see:

- Between 5 and 8 php5-fpm processes that takes about 70-80% of CPU usage

The configurations are: (just the significative part)

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
worker_processes  8;

events{
    worker_connections  1024;
    multi_accept off;
}

http{
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  30;
    tcp_nodelay        off;
    client_max_body_size 64m;
    gzip  on;
}
```

***/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf***

```
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 10
pm.start_servers = 3
pm.min_spare_servers = 2
pm.max_spare_servers = 4
pm.process_idle_timeout = 5s;
pm.max_requests = 400
```

The Server specs:

- 24Gb of RAM
- Inter Xeon 8 Cores

What do you think about this problem? Is it caused by a server configuration not optimal? What configuration do you suggest for this server?

Comment: It is really impossible to know without seeing the said scripts that are hitting PHP. Are you hitting CPU or memory limits? You said it is using 70-80%, what was it before? Is it slowness in PHP or in the network latency on the ajax scripts?

Answer (score 1):

With 24 GB of RAM you should increase these settings

```
pm.max_children
pm.start_servers
pm.min_spare_servers
pm.max_spare_servers
```

to something more sane for your server. Your current settings are in a sort of "nice at home to play with" setting.

For example, see "Tuning PHP5-FPM" [here](http://tuxlite.com/2012/07/tuning-php/) and do the math. My guess would be to start out by multiplying the numbers by 10 or so.

Anyway, your PHP application could still be linear CPU-bound instead of worker-bound and tuning would not help a thing.

Comment: @boblith Glad to hear that. Please consider accepting the answer.